# How to install dependencies in the vendor directory of a Go project for running k8s.io/code-generator/generate-groups.sh

Tags: go, kubernetes, dependencies, code-generation, client-go

I don't have much experience in working with go projects so I am not exactly sure how the go modules feature works. I am following along the sample-controller from the book 'Programming Kubernetes' which describes creating a custom operator, and the client code is generated using a code generator from the k8s.io/code_generation package. The way to generate this code is by running the file k8s.io/code-generator/generate-groups.sh,

```
vendor/k8s.io/code-generator/generate-groups.sh all \
github.com/programming-kubernetes/cnat/cnat-client-go/pkg/generated
github.com/programming-kubernetes/cnat/cnat-client-go/pkg/apis \
cnat:v1alpha1 \
--output-base "${GOPATH}/src" \
--go-header-file "hack/boilerplate.go.txt"
```

I am not that clear on the inputs to this shell script either.
So far, I have tried using `go mod init <module_path>` to create a go.mod file, and then running go get commands to get all the dependencies listed in the go.mod file. I do not know how to get all the dependencies installed in the local directory so that I can run the shell script from the package.

Comment: That looks like a very outdated book, so you're likely going to have to modify the build process or find an updated build script. You won't find non-source files in `vendor/`, and `GOPATH/src` is deprecated and no longer used.